# I am not getting attribute name from xml response in php?

Tags: php, xml

I am getting XML response from API but I am facing a little problem. I can not get `name` an attribute from XML response.

I am sharing image XML response data.
[image]

Here is my code which I am trying to get `name` attribute but I can not getting so Please help me.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($xml);die();
```

when I execute my above code it is not displayed `name` attributes like `order_id, origin,destination`.it is displayed 0,1,2 keys rather than displayed `name` attributes.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 1.0
        )

    [object] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [pk] => 1
                    [model] => awb
                )

            [field] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 899594723
                    [1] => 800000041
                    [2] => 1.13
                    [3] => JHANSI - JHA
                    [4] => DELHI - DLO
                    [5] => DELHI - DLO
                    [6] => DLO
                    [7] => KAMASHYA ONLINE SHOPPING - 331428
                    [8] => R G
                    [9] => 28-Jan-2018
                    [10] => Delivered / Closed
                    [11] => Delivered
                    [12] => 999 - Delivered
                    [13] => Delivered
                    [14] => 999
                    [15] => Self:R G: Android
                    [16] => 0.0000000
                    [17] => 0.0000000
                    [18] => 01-Feb-2018
                    [19] => 01-Feb-2018
                    [20] => 01-Feb-2018 12:44
                    [21] => 2018-02-01 12:43:00
                    [22] => None
                    [23] => 0
                    [24] => 2018-02-01 12:44:20
                    [25] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => CharField
                                    [name] => rts_system_delivery_status
                                )

                        )

                    [26] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => CharField
                                    [name] => rts_reason_code_number
                                )

                        )

                    [27] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => CharField
                                    [name] => rts_last_update
                                )

                        )

                    [28] => 110019
                    [29] => DELHI
                    [30] => New Delhi
                    [31] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => CharField
                                    [name] => delivery_pod_image
                                )

                        )

                    [32] => http://api3.ecomexpress.in//static/lastmile//sign/2018/2/1/sign_899594723_2018020112441517469260.png
                    [33] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => CharField
                                    [name] => rev_pickup_signature
                                )

                        )

                    [34] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => CharField
                                    [name] => rev_pickup_packed_image
                                )

                        )

                    [35] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => CharField
                                    [name] => rev_pickup_open_image
                                )

                        )

                 )
)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read up about SimpleXML, then you'll find that doing a `print_r` doesn't give all of the data.  If you wanted the `name` attribute of the `field` elements, then you can do something like...

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
foreach ( $xml->object[0]->field as $field )   {
    echo $field['name'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

The `foreach` will go take the loaded XML and then pick out the first `object` element (the [0] will pick the first) and within that each of the `field` elements.  The `echo` line uses the array notation to fetch the `name` attribute.

If you wanted a specific `object` element,then you can use XPath to find this object and do similar to the above and print each one out...

```
$objectRec = $xml->xpath('//object[@pk="2"]')[0];
foreach ( $objectRec->field as $field )   {
    echo $field['name'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

The XPath above, picks out the `<object pk="2"...>` element.  Note that `->xpath()` returns an array of matching nodes, so again here I'm just using the first one ([0]).

To help check the elements you've selected and when `print_r` isn't much help, you can use `asXML()` to output the XML of a node...

```
$objectRec = $xml->xpath('//object[@pk="1"]')[0];
echo $objectRec->asXML();
```

Comment: @NilgelRen Thank you very much for help.